# T-SQL Select all combinations of ranges that meet aggregate criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, aggregate

### Problem restated per comments

Say we have the following integer id's and counts...

```
id   count
1    0
2    10
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    9
8    0
```

We also have a variable `@id_range int`.

Given a value for `@id_range`, how can we select all combinations of id **ranges**, without using while loops or cursors, that meet the following criteria?

**1) No two ranges in a combination can overlap (min and max of each range are inclusive)

2) `sum(count)` for a combination of ranges must equal `sum(count)` of the initial data set (20 in this case)

3) Only include ranges where `sum(count)` > 0**

The simplest case would be when `@id_range = max(id) - min(id)`, or 7 given the above data. In this case, there's only one solution:

```
minId   maxId   count
---------------------
1       8       20
```

But if `@id_range = 1` for example, there would be 4 possible solutions:

Solution 1:

```
minId   maxId   count
---------------------
1      2        10
5      6        1
7      8        9
```

Solution 2:

```
minId   maxId   count
---------------------
1      2        10
6      7        10
```

Solution 3:

```
minId   maxId   count
---------------------
2       3       10
5       6       1
7       8       9
```

Solution 4:

```
minId   maxId   count
---------------------
2       3       10
6       7       10
```

The end goal is to identify which solutions have the fewest number of ranges (solution # 2 and 4, in above example where `@id_range = 1`).

Comment: There appear to be duplicated rows in the expected output.  What is the logic behind that?

Comment: what is `t`, `rc` ? How does `first table` related to `second table`  ?

Comment: The duplication is needed because there can be multiple collections of rows that meet the criteria. But I'd be ok with a more intuitive way of returning the results.

Comment: `rc` is abbreviation for row combination, that is a collection of rows in the range table that fulfill the criteria. `t` is the total count from first table. so first 2 rows of 1st table are aggregated as first row of 2nd table.

Comment: so the input to your problem is actually second table ? is first table relevant at all ?

Comment: Correct, I only provided the first table to show how the second was derived. But yes, the only input is the 2nd table and given as the last code snippet.

Comment: The 1st table is also to help explain criteria #2 (total must equal 20)

Comment: If `a = min(id)` and `b = max(id)`, doesn't that constitute an `rc` that has only one entry and is therefore minimal, and satisfies all your criteria? I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: The range between each `a` and `b` is already given to be 1 for this example, but I can see the confusion. Maybe I should restate the problem? I could only show the initial ids/counts along with what the range needs to be (again, 1 in this case). That way I wouldn't need to show the second table at all.

Comment: Ok, got rid of 2nd table and reworded the post. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: yes. it is much clearer. So you want to find which `@id_range` has fewest solution OR for a given `@id_range`  what is the solution with fewest combination ?

Comment: The latter... for a given `@id_range` what is the solution with the fewest combinations. But like for `@id_range = 1` in the example, I think there can be more than one solution.

Comment: Beg your pardon, but is this a real task or just some exercise? I'd wager it's exercise.

Comment: It's a simplified, generic version of a real task.

Comment: you could have replied .rephrase your question with Sample and output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this solution does not list all possible combination but just try to get group it in smallest possible no of rows.

Hopefully it will cover all possible scenario

```
-- create the sample table
declare @sample table
(
    id  int,
    [count] int
)

-- insert some sample data
insert into @sample select 1,     0
insert into @sample select 2,    10
insert into @sample select 3,     0
insert into @sample select 4,     0
insert into @sample select 5,     0
insert into @sample select 6,     1
insert into @sample select 7,     9
insert into @sample select 8,     0

-- the @id_range
declare @id_range   int = 1

-- the query
; with
cte as
(
    -- this cte identified those rows with count > 0 and group them together
    -- sign(0) gives 0, sign(+value) gives 1
    -- basically it is same as case when [count] > 0 then 1 else 0 end
    select  *, 
            grp = row_number() over (order by id) 
                - dense_rank() over(order by sign([count]), id)
    from    @sample
),
cte2 as
(
    -- for each grp in cte, assign a sub group (grp2). each sub group 
    -- contains @id_range number of rows
    select  *, 
            grp2 = (row_number() over (partition by grp order by id) - 1) 
                 / (@id_range + 1)
    from    cte
    where   count   > 0
)
select  MinId   = min(id), 
        MaxId   = min(id) + @id_range, 
        [count] = sum(count)
from    cte2
group by grp, grp2
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to answer the question as stated, though the id's may not be contiguous. So I don't think it works for something like `insert into @sample values (4625,2),(4750,3),(4875,4),(5125,1),(5250,1),(5375,3),(5500,1)` and `declare @id_range   int = 500`

Comment: if the `id` is not continuous, you will need to use `row_number()` to generate one and use it in the `CTE`. Edited the query